# How to reassign small polygons to its nearest neighbor in R (similar to gdal_sieve.py function)?

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapefile, gdal

I created a spatial polygon file from a gridded dataset using the grid2polygons function in R. I would now like to take that polygon file and merge any polygons containing less than 6 pixels with its nearest largest neighbor. In the image link, you can see an example of small polygons circled in blue. I would like those merged with the larger surround polygon.

[Polygon Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BLvP.jpg)

There is a function in Gdal: gdal_sieve.py that can do exactly this (http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html) if you would like to get an idea of exactly what I would like to do. Does anyone know of a way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

...pretty late but it may still be useful to someone ;)

It took me a while to study and test...and there is still room for improvement. Nevertheless, it solved my problem!

```
sieve_slivers = function(x, area.thr=NULL, neigh.case="rook" ){

  if( is.null(area.thr) | area.thr <= 0 ){ stop("Area threshold parameter is wrong or missing") }

  if ( !is(x, "sf") ){ x = st_as_sf(x) }

  if( tolower(neigh.case) == "rook"){ neigh.case = "F***1****" } else { neigh.case = "F***T****" }

  x = x %>%
    mutate( ID = 1:n(), # assign ID first
            area_mq = as.numeric(st_area(.)) )

  newID = do.call(c,
                  lapply(which(x$area_mq <= area.thr), function(g){
                    tmp = st_relate(x[g,], x, pattern = neigh.case )# check: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/234
                    tmp = x[tmp[[1]],] %>%
                      st_drop_geometry()

                    if( nrow(tmp)>0 ){
                      out = tmp[which.max(tmp$area_mq),"ID"] # in case of 2 or more polygons with the same area, it takes the first
                    } else {
                      out = NA_real_ # for isolated polygons #x$ID[g]
                    }
                    return(out)
                  }) )

  x$ID[which(x$area_mq <= area.thr)] = newID

  # final dissolve
  x = x %>%
    filter( !is.na(ID) ) %>% # remove tiny isolated polygons that could not be merged to anything
    group_by( ID ) %>%
    summarise( area_mq = sum(area_mq, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    mutate( ID = NULL)

  return(x)
}
```

Comment: It'd be cool if you had used some test data with it and showed the results here. Still, it's great that you've attempted something here. :)